# ServletContextListener is stopping the deployment of Web Application on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servletcontextlistener

I have implemented a ServletContextListener in Simple java class.Now inside this i have called a method to execute as soon as contextInitialized of ServletContextListener  runs.The nature of called method is that it is complex and takes long time hours to execute.
There is only one web page called index.jsp which is welcome page that needs to displayed on browser as soon as web application runs but this is not displaying as first called method executes and it takes long time to execute..

I need welcome page to display and function called in ServletContextListener to execute in background ..

Here is my ServletContextListener  class..

```
public class Startup implements ServletContextListener
{
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
    // Do your startup work here
     executeprocess();
}

}
```

and here is my web.xml file..

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.myapp.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why dont you delegate the operation on a separate thread?

Comment: @Kal is it not possible in this way ..

Comment: What exactly is you problem then ? Could you provide more details ?

Comment: @benjamin.d i want to execute a function which takes hours to complete in background evrry time the machine on which the Apache tomcat is installed reboots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding thread as below:

```
@Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        executeprocess();
    }
}).start();}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for ur answer .I have one doubt on the above code that on adding above code snippet first welcome page will be launched then executeprocess(); will be called..Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

The `contextInitialized` method will pause the deployment until the method finishes.

Comment: If you really want to run it as part of the deployment, and you don't want to wait for the method to finish, then you have to use threads.

Comment: I have a doubt that does tomcat deploys a project every time machine reboots ?